# Can anyone explain ![]/[] == true statement in js?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(true == []); // -> false    
console.log(true == ![]); // -> false
```

Why they are always false?

Comment: Why would they be anything but false?

Comment: `[]` is an array, which is truthy but not equal to true. `![]` is `false` so not true either. `!![] == true` will be true

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: 1) true does not equal an array 2) true does not equal false

Comment: @VLAZ that article dosen’t talks about arrays.

Comment: @WeijingJayLin because they list falsey values. Everything else is truthy. Ergo, an array - empty or not, is truthy.

Comment: @VLAZ that’s what I thought, but truthy dosen’t means it is true value what confused me. So the topic is related, but different.

Comment: @WeijingJayLin truthy means that it will be converted to `true` if turned into a boolean. It doesn't mean that it equals `true`, since we're now talking about [`==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) and [type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523765/how-does-js-type-coercion-work). Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703222/why-is-false-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662231/evaluates-to-true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`true == []` is `false` simply because `true` is not equal to `[]`.

`![]` evaluates to `false`, so `true == ![]` is `false`.

Also, `true == !![]` is `true`.